# Given the screen dimensions, I want to fill the screen with square boxes. How to do it?

Tags: react-native, gridview

I have a requirement where I have to fill the screen with square boxes.
**NOTE**: The boxes should not be scrollable. They should fit exactly in the screen size.

The size of the box should also be dynamic based on width & height of screen.

Demo Reference:[image]

Comment: `import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native'; [...] const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions()` and then you can divide the values according to your request

Comment: or simply [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/2uTLvjgbG)